# html5 canvas - draw arc on top of image (not using image onload)

Tags: jquery, html, css, fabricjs

trying to draw an arc on top of background image

My Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qeqg6/

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200,350,50,0*Math.PI,1.5*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://placehold.it/350x150', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

There is a stackoverflow question but it does not help in my case. [HTML5 Canvas - my lines/arcs are not appearing on top of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809852/html5-canvas-my-lines-arcs-are-not-appearing-on-top-of-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you can simply use css (even without jQuery, actually):

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

$('#c').css('background-image','url(http://placehold.it/350x150)');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200,350,50,0*Math.PI,1.5*Math.PI);

ctx.stroke();
```

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qeqg6/2/)**

Comment: Thanks Alex. However I had tried this before and the problem was that the arc disappears when you click on the canvas. This problem exists in your fiddle too. try it. try clicking on the canvas.

Comment: well this appears to be caused by fabric, what is this anyways? when you do it plain JS it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Qeqg6/3/

Comment: I am using fabricjs wrapper for canvas manipulation. Hence I have to use fabricjs.